# how to add ssl.cer file in my react-native project (Unable to make https request in react-native-android)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I tried hit **https** get a request from react native mobile app. I got an error as a network request failed. but I am able to hit **HTTP** request with the same app, tried to change many configurations in react-native android manifest files nothing worked out for me. finally, I predicted an SSL certificate is required to make **https** request.

Now I don't know how to add ssl.cer file in my react-native project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in android or ios?

Comment: does the endpoint support https?

Comment: Hello Kavi,welcome to stackoverflow! It looks like this is your first post here, if I may suggest, it will be nice if you could provide more details information (error log, example code, screenshots, method you tried to solve your issue) to the community hence we could better support you with your issue.  :)